How to configure both couchbaseTransactionManager and transactionManager in spring boot 3?
I am using both oracle database and couch base database in my spring boot project.
With spring boot 2.6.0 and java 8 , application was working properly but when I migrated to spring boot 3.0.9 and java 17 I started getting below error :
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.transaction.TransactionManager' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: couchbaseTransactionManager,transactionManager
Any help or guidance is appreciated.
